# Is there a way to find who holds the trademark?

Tags: home-improvement

[WonderBoard](https://www.thespruce.com/wonderboard-backer-board-1822682) is a cement-based backer board mainly used for tiling in wet places. Specifically, its components are Portland cement, expanded polystyrene (EPS) beads, aggregates, and fiberglass reinforcement.

It looks like WonderBoard is also a trademark/

[image]

Is there a way to find who holds the trademark?

Comment: Quick googling suggests it's manufactured by custombuildingproducts.com so at the very least they should probably know.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for your comments. How to find out it's manufactured by custombuildingproducts.com? in other words, is there somewhere in that site tells this explicitly?

Comment: I googled "wonderboard-lite manufacturer" and found a site which linked to the manufacturer's site in their results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (r) symbol indicates this is a registered trademark, and as such has registered with the US Patent and Trademark Office. The USPTO maintains a public searchable [database](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/gate.exe?f=tess&state=4807:luw4a3.1.1) of all registered marks. A little trial and error reveals the pertinent search term here, is "Wonder Board" including the space. This [mark](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4807:luw4a3.2.2) is registered to Modulars, Inc. This same corporation appears to hold the mark "wonder-board" as well, dating from the 70s and 80s.